# Jquery not hiding panels in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am currently working on moving server side code to the client side. I have multiple panels with IDs which I am trying to show and hide based on a radio button click. I have the clicks working correctly but its not showing or hiding the panels. I am new to C# so any help will be appreciated. Here is what I have tried.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

   if (inputs.length > 0) {
       for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
           if (inputs[i].type == "radio") {
               inputs[i].onclick = function () {
                   if (this.value == "0")
                   {
                       $("[id$=test1]").show();
                   } else if (this.value == "1")
                   {
                       $("[id$=test2]").show();
                   } else if (this.value == "2")
                   {
                       $("[id$=test3]").show();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

My asp.net code is in the following format:

```
<Table>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
            <label>
            </label>
        </TableCell>
     </TableRow>
     <TableRow>
         <TableCell>
             <RadioButtonList>
                 <ListItem value = "0"></ListItem>
                 <ListItem value = "1"></ListItem>
                 <ListItem value = "2"></ListItem>
             </RadioButtonList>
         </TableCell>
         <TableCell>
         <Table>
             <TableRow>
                 <TableCell>
                     <Panel id="test1" style="display:none;"></Panel>
                     <Panel id="test2" style="display:none;"></Panel>
                     <Panel id="test3" style="display:none;"></Panel> 
                 </TableCell>
             </TableRow>
         </Table>
         </TableCell>
     </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Inside panels there are table->TableRow->TableCells

I am having issues showing and hiding the panels based on the IDs. I have tried using javascript to get the element and change the display to none or block. Also tried adding display none property to all the panels.

Comment: Are you using WebForms?

Comment: I am not familiar with Webforms. Based on my limited experience I would say yes it is using WebForms.

Comment: Is the "format" that you show the actual markup (or HTML output)? I am asking the question because there are problems in that table structure.

Comment: that is the current table structure. I am starting to look into making it better by removing unnecessary structure.

Comment: I suggest indenting the markup. It helps to see what is wrong. Each Table should contain only TableRows, and each TableRow should contain only TableCell(s).

Comment: @NepCoder can you post your complete markup from your .aspx file

Comment: @PrashanthThurairatnam I have added a complete markup of my .aspx file without including too much information. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have cleaned the code and I am still not sure why tables were created. I tried removing them but it messes with the layout. Let me know if I need to make any more changes.

Comment: @NepCoder Your aspx code is still not complete (usually you will have server controls). Anyway, check my answer. Since you've mentioned that you have limited experience with WebForms I've tried to answer with much help. Remember to leave the page directive in your new page. Just delete everything below it and replace with my test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate all your help trying to help me figure out my problem. I have fixed the problem and it was related to the code in the back-end which was adding the visible=false to the panel id. While trying to debug the issue I noticed that only one panel was loaded in the html. I remove the code from the back-end to remove the visible=false and then I was able to make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the id portion in single quotes.

`$("[id$=test1]").show();`

to

`$("[id$='test1']").show();`

Comment: It does not seem to work. It does not hide the panels. There are no client side errors.

Comment: Yep, just noticed I overlooked something. Putting single quotes around the ids should get you a step further.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be that difficult. FYI: I'm just pasting below the entire markup + code that would go on this test.aspx page.

Just create a web form named test.aspx page. Delete default code under the [page directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) and replace it with this. Set this as the start page and run from Visual Studio. You will see it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table
        {
            border: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        .hide
        {
            display: none;
        }
        .red
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .blue
        {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .green
        {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .yellow
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .violet
        {
            background-color: violet;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>   
                 </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="test1" CssClass="red hide"> 
                        <div>
                            Panel 1 text
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="test2" CssClass="blue hide"> 
                        <div>
                            Panel 2 text
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="test3" CssClass="green hide"> 
                        <div>
                            Panel 3 text
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="test4" CssClass="yellow hide"> 
                        <div>
                            Panel 4 text
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="test5" CssClass="violet hide"> 
                        <div>
                            Panel 5 text
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            if (inputs.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (inputs[i].type == "radio") {
                        inputs[i].onclick = function () {
                            if (this.value == "0") {
                                $("[id^=test]").hide();
                                $("#test1").show();                                
                            } else if (this.value == "1") {
                                $("[id^=test]").hide();
                                $("#test2").show();
                            } else if (this.value == "2") {
                                $("[id^=test]").hide();
                                $("#test3").show();
                            } else if (this.value == "3") {
                                $("[id^=test]").hide();
                                $("#test4").show();
                            } else if (this.value == "4") {
                                $("[id^=test]").hide();
                                $("#test5").show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is test id defined? I do not see any reference of it in the code that you have here.

Comment: My problem was related to the visible=false that was in the C# code while the page was loaded. Removed it and it started to work. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey @NepCoder glad you find your fix. FYI: `test` as an id doesn't exist. What I am doing in the code is to select all the panels staring with `test` as id (it is a regex selector where `^` indicates starting with). Hope this answers your first comment.

Comment: That makes sense. I am new to this and I really appreciate the detailed answer.